# Нужна ли запятая перед "НО" в предложении: "Термопаста под крышкой — главное «НО» на пути к успеху в этом деле"?

Tags: пунктуация, авторская-пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед "НО" в предложении: "Термопаста под крышкой — главное «НО» на пути к успеху в этом деле"?

В связи с чем здесь **не нужна** запятая? Это же союз?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> В связи с чем здесь не нужна запятая? Это же союз?

Запятая не нужна. "Но" здесь выступает в роли члена предложения и по грамматической роли союзом не является.

Вас даже кавычки не смутили? А они ведь как раз для таких случаев здесь и используются, когда слово в необычной роли выступает. Проверьте себя. Бывает у союза определение?

Comment: В роли какого члена предложения выступает "НО"?

Comment: @Максим *В роли какого члена предложения выступает "НО"* Ой, это отдельный разговор, лучше бы его обойти в данной теме. Школьная грамматика здесь оставляет некоторый простор для версий. Проще всего в рамках школьных положений считать, что "НО" здесь сказуемое, выраженное существительным в именительном падеже. https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/200-tiremegdupodlegawimiskazuemym.html

Answer (score 0):

Не нужна, но смысл фразы очень туманный. Зачем это "но"? Как оно может стоять "на пути к успеху"? Будьте проще. Скажем, "препятствие" чем плохо?

Comment: В связи с чем здесь не нужна запятая? Это же союз?

Comment: Нет, оно здесь в роли существительного.